# What is the method symbol for += in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
x + y
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
x.send(:+, y)
```

What is this a syntactic sugar for?

```
x += y
```

I've tried

```
x.send(:+=, y)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Aww, I might be corrected but I do no think there is one.

Comment: `+=` is not a method, it’s language-wide syntactic sugar for “increase and assign”. Overriding `+` will automatically impact `+=`.

Comment: It's an abbreviated assignment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a method. It is a short way (syntactic sugar) for writing following:

```
x = 1
#=> 1
x += 1 # same as x = x + 1
#=> 2
```

Comment: Is there a = method? x.send(:=,1) doesn't work either. I thought everything in Ruby is a method?

Comment: @syclee `=` is an assignment operator and it is not a method in Ruby

Comment: @syclee: How do you think that should work? You are creating `x` by `x = ...`. How could you send the method call to something yet-to-be-created?

Comment: @syclee `'everything in Ruby is a method'.sub('method', 'object')`

Comment: @Stefan I think he want to say, every operation is a method call.

Comment: @Stefan: no, it's not. Variables aren't objects, for example. If variables *were* objects, you could indeed have an `=` method in the `Variable` class. The closest you can get is `Bindingd#local_variable_set`.

Comment: A variable is a pointer to an object, it's not an object itself.

Comment: @under_gongor good point, but I don't think it's impossible for ruby, when it sees =, to creates variable x first, and then runs the = method on it.